# How can I calculate the relative risk for all pairs of conditions in a matrix in R?

Tags: r, statistics, vectorization

I have a data frame in R where each row is an individual and each column is a disease code. Each cell contains 1 or 0 to indicate whether the individual does or does not have the disease. For each disease code X, I want to separate the individuals that have disease X from those that do not have disease X. I then want to calculate the relative risk that patients with disease X also have disease Y or disease Z. Here is sample data and my approach:

```
# generate reproducible dataframe with disease diagnoses
set.seed(2)
ID = c(0:19)
disease0 = c(rbinom(10, 1, 0.0), rbinom(10, 1, 1.0))
disease1 = c(rbinom(10, 1, 0.1), rbinom(10, 1, 0.9))
disease2 = c(rbinom(10, 1, 0.5), rbinom(10, 1, 0.5))
disease3 = c(rbinom(10, 1, 0.9), rbinom(10, 1, 0.1))
disease4 = c(rbinom(10, 1, 1.0), rbinom(10, 1, 0.0))
(disease.df = data.frame(cbind(ID, disease0, disease1, disease2, disease3, disease4)))
row.names(disease.df) = disease.df[ ,1]
disease.df[ ,1] = NULL
disease.df

   disease0 disease1 disease2 disease3 disease4
0         0        0        1        0        1
1         0        0        0        1        1
2         0        0        1        1        1
3         0        0        0        1        1
4         0        1        0        0        1
5         0        1        0        1        1
6         0        0        0        0        1
7         0        0        0        1        1
8         0        0        1        1        1
9         0        0        0        1        1
10        1        1        0        0        0
11        1        1        0        0        0
12        1        1        1        0        0
13        1        1        1        1        0
14        1        1        1        0        0
15        1        1        1        0        0
16        1        0        1        0        0
17        1        1        0        1        0
18        1        1        1        0        0
19        1        1        0        0        0
```

I can use the following code to calculate the relative risk that an individual with disease 0 also has diseases 1 through 4.

```
colMeans(filter(disease.df, disease0 == 1))/colMeans(filter(disease.df, disease0 != 1))

 disease0  disease1  disease2  disease3  disease4 
      Inf 4.5000000 2.0000000 0.2857143 0.0000000
```

My question is, is there a way using vectorized operations or apply functions to do this for all 5 diseases while avoiding a for-loop. Ideally it would like to produce a table like this:

```
         disease0  disease1  disease2  disease3  disease4
diease0       Inf 4.5000000 2.0000000 0.2857143 0.0000000
diease1 7.3636364       Inf 1.0227273 0.4090909 0.2045455
diease2 1.8333333 1.0185185       Inf 0.6111111 0.5238095
diease3 0.3055556 0.4583333 0.6111111       Inf 2.8518519
diease4 0.0000000 0.2222222 0.5000000 3.5000000       Inf
```

Comment: I saved the above edits before seeing the below comment from Ronak. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an optimal solution, however it can help you from repetitive lines of code.

```
t(apply(df[-1], 2, function(x) {
   temp = lapply(split(df[-1], x), colMeans)
  temp[[2]]/temp[[1]]
 })
)

#          disease0  disease1  disease2  disease3  disease4
#disease0       Inf 4.5000000 2.0000000 0.2857143 0.0000000
#disease1 7.3636364       Inf 1.0227273 0.4090909 0.2045455
#disease2 1.8333333 1.0185185       Inf 0.6111111 0.5238095
#disease3 0.3055556 0.4583333 0.6111111       Inf 2.8518519
#disease4 0.0000000 0.2222222 0.5000000 3.5000000       Inf
```

If I have understood you correctly, we can do this by combination of `apply` and `lapply` calls.

For every column we `split` the dataframe in two parts (those with 1's and  those with 0's) and find the mean for every column using `colMeans` and divide the two sub-lists element-wise.